# Where to find config file for how many connection are permitted to the server

Tags: linux, session

I'm not very familiar with UNIX systems yet and I need to connect to one server by telnet. When I try to connect I get following massage

```
Connected to some.ip.
Escape character is '^]'.
too many active sessions
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So I guess I need to find config file where are defined how many active session are permitted to the host and increase it. But where should I look? Normally which file hold this configuration? Thank you!

The system is Linux RedHat old version.

**UPDATE**:

I found it where is it `/etc/xinetd.conf`
But currently is `instances = 60` and I have 13 connections. So the problem is something else.

Comment: Is this connection via SSH or telnet or FTP or what? What version of RH are you using exactly?

Comment: connection via `telnet` and according to `uname -mrs` I get `Linux 2.4.21-37.ELsmp i686`

Comment: A word of advice: Please use SSH to remotely administer the box instead of telnet.

Comment: @L0j1k, I have SSH and Telnet connetion to this server. I'm currently connected via SSH but there is something that I can use only via telnet. That's why I also need telnet.